# Percorrer um array e separar os nomes iguais para fazer as devidas alterações

Tags: php, array

Preciso percorrer um array que tem os seguintes elementos:

```
$MeuArray = array("PEDRO" ,"PEDRO" ,"PEDRO" ,"PEDRO" ,"JOAO" ,"JOAO", "JOAO", "JOAO");
```

Preciso separar pelos nomes iguais, exemplo: quero pegar os nomes que são iguais a `"PEDRO'` para fazer as devidas modificações depois continuar fazendo com o restante dos nomes.

Como posso fazer isso?

Comment: Você quer deixar os arrays unicos, tipo deixar só um array "PEDRO", ou quer uma comparação pra todos os array "PEDRO" e jogar um valor neles?

Comment: Ao lado desses arrays tem outro elementos, exemplo: 
PEDRO Brasil        3242 3
PEDRO Brasil        8732 1
PEDRO Argentina 5423 2

Quando eu separar os nomes iguais agora eu preciso fazer as outras validaçoes com os dados deste pedro, pois o mesmo PEDRO tem vários cadastros.

Comment: Está pouco claro o que precisas... queres dizer que queres organizar a array? pois quando dizes "separar pelos nomes iguais" não é claro o que procuras.

Comment: Acho que não seria muito adequado o mesmo "PEDRO" ter vários cadastros. Não seria melhor organizar utilizando um "ID", para que saiba qual é cada um de forma única?

Comment: É um sistema antigo, foi criado desse jeito. Por isso "PEDRO" tem vários cadastros.

Answer (score 0):

Bom, se eu entendi bem, creio que seja isso, podes utilizar uma combinação de `for` e `if` para saber quando  fazer as devidas alterações. Utilizando seu exemplo:

```
$MeuArray = array("PEDRO" ,"PEDRO" ,"PEDRO" ,"PEDRO" ,"JOAO" ,"JOAO", "JOAO", "JOAO");

for ($i=0; $i <count($MeuArray) ; $i++) { 

    if($MeuArray[$i] == 'PEDRO')
    {
        // Faça aqui as devidas alterações para PEDRO
        // Podes criar um novvo array se desejar
        // Para utilizar o array atual $MeuArray[$i]['PEDRO'];
            echo "Teste";
        }
    }
```

E para pegar todos os nomes, você teria que ter um array com todos os nomes, como o do exemplo que você postou em `$MeuArray`.

Possuindo esse array, você pode utilizar a `array_unique`. Por exemplo:

```
$MeuArray = array("PEDRO" ,"PEDRO" ,"PEDRO" ,"PEDRO" ,"JOAO" ,"JOAO", "JOAO", "JOAO");
$result = array_unique($MeuArray);
```

O exemplo irá imprimir:

```
Array
(
    [0] => PEDRO
    [1] => JOAO

)
```

Qualquer coisa só falar.

Att;

Comment: E como eu poderia fazer pra ele jogar em outro array os nomes que são iguais, por exemplo: ele vai ir ler um arquivo que tem 100 nomes, mas os nomes iguais estao em ordem(PEDRO, PEDRO, PEDRO, JOAO, JOAO, JOAO, CARLOS, CARLOS, CARLOS) ai como eu faço para diferenciar os nomes? Porque o seu exemplo ele ta uma coisa simples, pegando exatamente o nome PEDRO, ta feito para este exemplo. Obrigado!